# Refresh HTML Component on window size change

Tags: angular

I want to change the `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` variables after the window size changes. I've tried using a `@HostListener` to detect when the window size changes but the `ngx-slick` component doesn't update after those variables are changed.

.ts

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.updateSlidesToShow(window.innerWidth);
}

updateSlidesToShow(width: number) {
  if (width < 576) {
    this.slideConfig.slidesToShow = 1;
    this.slideConfig.slidesToScroll = 1;
  } else {
    this.slideConfig.slidesToShow = 3;
    this.slideConfig.slidesToScroll = 3;
  }
}

slideConfig = {
  'slidesToShow': 3,
  'slidesToScroll': 3,
  'dots': true,
  'autoplay': true,
  'autoplaySpeed': 10000,
};
```

.html

```
<ngx-slick class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig">
  <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide" style="padding: 0 10px">
    <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
  </div>
</ngx-slick>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a *limitation* in the `ngx-slick` because he expects the `config` object to be passed and angular will not run the change detection after changing any property in that object.

The `config` object passed to the component `ngx-slick` will not be reevaluated as angular do not know it's changed as it's not feeling that properties are affected.

The only workaround that I do suggest is recreating the component after changing the width of the screen as I implemented in the following demo 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fucgug

Comment: That's actually a pretty smart workaround. However, it seems very resource intensive, therefore is it possible to to get the window width (and send it over to the `updateSlidesToShow`) after x seconds instead of ASAP?